# Constructor creates const object

Tags: c++

Why I'm getting error

```
../implicit-explicit.cpp:44:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘BWSize&’ from an rvalue of type ‘char’
../implicit-explicit.cpp:36:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void func(BWSize&)’
```

when I remove `const` from function void `func(const BWSize & s)`

According to my understanding constructor returns not const value.

Code

```
// implicit-explicit.cpp by Bill Weinman <http://bw.org/>
#include <iostream>

const std::size_t maxlen = 1024;    // maximum length of bwString

class BWSize {
    std::size_t _size;
public:
    BWSize(std::size_t);    // constructor: size from int
    BWSize(const char *);   // constructor: size from c-string
    std::size_t size() const;
};

BWSize::BWSize(const std::size_t n) {
    std::cout << "BWSize from int" << std::endl;
    _size = (n <= maxlen) ? n : 0;
}

BWSize::BWSize(const char * s) {
    std::cout << "constructor: BWSize from c-string" << std::endl;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
        if(s[i] == '\0') {
            _size = i;
            return;
        }
    }
    _size = 0;
}

std::size_t BWSize::size() const {
    return _size;
}

using namespace std;

void func(const BWSize & s) {
    cout << "s.size() is " << s.size() << endl;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    BWSize s = 'x';
    cout << "s.size() is " << s.size() << endl;
    func('x');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: small note: you can declare your constructor `explicit` to avoid implicit conversion (if not wanted)

Comment: Sure you didn't mean `func("x")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call:

```
func('x');
```

requires that a temporary `BWSize` object be created (via a call to an implicit converting constructor) . And you cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your function call in main to **func(s)** will work. But I don't know what the final output you want.